# Error In Python Code Trying to Upload an Excel File for Pixel Art

Tags: python, excel

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("PixelArt.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
""cells = tuple(ws['A1':'AC13'])""

color_dict = {}

for row in cells:
  for cell in row:
    if cell.fill.patternType != None:
      color = cell.fill.fgColor.rgb
      if color not in color_dict:
        color_dict[color] = 1
      else:
        color_dict[color] += 1
      cellPos = cell.coordinate
      ws[cellPos].value = color_dict[color]

print(color_dict)
```

The Line in double quotes continues to pop up an error on the section "ws" i have tried many different ways to fix the issue including "iter_rows" and getting rid of "tuple", but nothing seems to work. It continues to say "No such file or directory" only on that line and the second to last line again on "ws". Any ideas?

Comment: Your description of the error is confusing -- I don't see how `tuple()` could possibly cause a FileNotFound error.  Please post the actual full error traceback message, so we don't have to guess what you meant.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought. There is no reason to have the FileNotFound where it is, but I have tried to see if there is any explanation using AI and it has proved unhelpful. I figured that "ws" my have been improperly defined above the error, but found nothing.

Comment: "__getitem__" method not defined on type "_WorkbookChild"

Comment: That is certainly not "No such file or directory" as you said in the post.  I'll ask again -- please edit the question and add the full error traceback message, so we don't have to guess exactly what the error is and where it happened.

Comment: "__getitem__" method not defined on type "_WorkbookChild" /nix/store/xf54733x4chbawkh1qvy9i1i4mlscy1c-python3-3.10.11/bin/python3: can't open file '/home/runner/Homework-4-cderidde/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: As @John Gordon states *please [edit] the question and add the **full error traceback** message*. The full traceback so the complete execution with line numbers can be seen and dont add as a comment add it to your question (formatted as code). Also what version of Openpyxl are you running?

Comment: Also if you have some cells with theme colours then `cell.fill.fgColor.rgb` will not return a hex value